# How to inject a unique module for each controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller

In the same way as $scope is independent of each controller. Exists the way to create a module independent for each controller?

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).service('mymodule', function () {});

angular.module('myapp', ['mymodule'])

.controller('myController2', function($scope, mymodule) {

    console.log(
      $scope.hello,   // undefined
      mymodule.hello, // "world"
      s === $scope,   // false
      m === mymodule  // true
    );

})

.controller('myController', function($scope, mymodule) {

    s = $scope;
    m = mymodule;
    $scope.hello = "world";
    mymodule.hello = "world";

});
```

http://jsbin.com/qazeju/2/edit?js,console

I tried with factory's and providers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to inject an independent instance into each controller, but you could define your service with a function to create an instance and call the function from each controller.

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).service('mymodule', function () {
  return {
    createMyService: function(){
      return {
        hello: 'hello world'
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a single module with DI? This is a little bit tricky, but I think this is possible, using an assetBuilder and injecting the result...